# How can I build a Form displaying a collection of collections?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

First of all, I have this DB schema:

[image: DB schema]

I have `categories`, which contain `products`.
I also have `attributes` (for example "color"), which contain `values` (for example "red", "green", etc).

So, finally, I can assign these `attributes` to `products` through the table `ProductAttributeValues`, that associates an `attribute value` to a `product`, this table is automatically created by Doctrine, because `Product` and `AttributeValue` have a ManyToMany relation between them.

This way I can have a `category` (cars) with `products` (Renault Megane, Ford Focus, etc). Each `product` can have multiple `attributes` with their `values` (color: gray, engine type: gasoline, etc). In this last example, the color is an `Attribute`, and gray is an `AttributeValue`. The engine type is another `Attribute`, and gasoline is an `AttributeValue`.

Ok, once I have my entities filled up with data (categories, attributes, attribute values, and products), how can I create a form to associate `attributes` and `values` for a given `product`?

More or less, the form should look like this:

[image: form]

So, as I'm in the "cars" `category`, I must display all `attributes` that belong to this `category` (engine and color). At the same time, I must display all `values` for these `attributes` (gasoline, diesel, electric... for the engine, and gray, red, blue... for the color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for collection field-types but [**entity**](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html) field-types with a **queryBuilder** if you are trying to build a form like the one on your image.

With the **entity field-type** you can [**group**](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by) your *attributes* by i.e. car.category.

... or you can use two entity fields and filter the results ( i.e. only showing attributes for category gas ) for the other selectbox in the field's queryBuilder. Best achieved by using an injected category property in your form builder being used in the queryBuilder's ->where() statement.

The [**collection** form-type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html) would be needed if you wanted to add/remove/edit multiple new categories or attributes to existing ones. but then your form would look different obviously.

Comment: Take into account the tables that I have, especially the Attribute and AttributeValue entities.

Comment: I did, what's your point on this? aside the fact that your schema looks weird to me - because the ProductAttributeValues table is not really necessary  ... what you want to achieve can be be done with the entity field and the correct query. That's what you asked for right?

Comment: Please read carefully, that table that looks weird to you is automatically created by Doctrine due to the ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it generates just a select tag with grouped options, but it does not solve fully the problem I was describing.